# Haskell MongoDB object to Bson

Tags: mongodb, haskell

I'm trying to build a sample code from `bson-mapping` module but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Session where

import Data.Bson.Mapping
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Data (Typeable)

data Post = Post { time :: UTCTime
                 , author :: String
                 , content :: String
                 , votes :: Int
                 }
          deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Typeable)
$(deriveBson ''Post)
```

I get the following error:

```
/src/mapping/Session.hs:27:3: error:
    • Could not deduce (MonadFail m)
        arising from a use of ‘Data.Bson.lookup’
      from the context: Monad m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   fromBson :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                               Monad m =>
                               Data.Bson.Document -> m Post
        at src/mapping/Session.hs:27:3-19
      Possible fix:
        add (MonadFail m) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fromBson :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                        Monad m =>
                        Data.Bson.Document -> m Post
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        con_alkG <- (Data.Bson.lookup Data.Bson.Mapping.consField) doc_alkH
      In the expression:
        do con_alkG <- (Data.Bson.lookup Data.Bson.Mapping.consField)
                         doc_alkH
           case con_alkG :: Text of
             "Post" -> do ...
             _ -> fail "Couldn't find right constructor"
      In the expression:
        \ doc_alkH
          -> do con_alkG <- (Data.Bson.lookup Data.Bson.Mapping.consField)
                              doc_alkH
                case ... of
                  "Post" -> ...
                  _ -> ...
   |
27 | $(deriveBson ''Post)
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Weird, since It is the actual doc example. can you add a function in which you use `fromBson` and `toBson` within the `IO` monad.

Comment: Eventually, I ended up using `bson-generic` package which `Just` works

Comment: @Nik You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `bson-mapping` hasn't been updated in 3 years and doesn't support the MonadFail proposal, which GHC 8.8.1 and newer have fully implemented. The right way to fix this is to update `bson-mapping` and change `fromBson   :: Monad m => Document -> m a` to `fromBson   :: MonadFail m => Document -> m a`. Ideally, upstream would do this for you, but you can do it in a local fork yourself. Alternatively, you can downgrade to GHC 8.6.5, which still allows the old, dangerous use of `fail`.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I ended up using `bson-generic` package which `Just` works